# How to simulate a mouse click in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, browser

I wants to be able to simulate mouse clicks on a WebBroswer in vb.net (even when the program in not on top, it will run in the background) How would I do this? I want it to click on a button every one second in the webBrowser. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider sending an `HttpWebRequest` yourself instead.

Comment: @Slaks Thanks, but I need to be able to click on the button

Comment: No; you probably don't.  You can send the request that the button results in.

Comment: They are random buttons, I don't always know what it is going to be

Answer (score 0):

Warning: This is an awful hack using an Excel 4 macro. It's actually written in VBScript, but if I'm not mistaken the syntax is similar if not identical in .NET. Of course, you need Excel to be installed.

```
Set Excel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")

' Where on the screen do you want to click?
i = "111"
j = "222"

Excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro ( _
    "CALL(""user32"",""SetCursorPos"",""JJJ""," & i & "," & j & ")")

WScript.Sleep 100
Excel.Quit
Set Excel = Nothing
```

Looking forward to more elegant answers!

Answer (score 0):

you will have a limited number of actions, that are valid after clicking. Use a timer and at each timer-tick select one of the actions randomly, numbering them sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Before you Excel.Quit....

do the following:

```
WScript.Sleep(100)
```

The following is like simulation of mouse left click:
do a IE focus OR app focus:

```
'objIE.document.focus()
'myShell.sendkeys ("{enter}")
```